Why are We Told to Avoid Extended Conversations in Comments?
I fail to understand the rationale for that nagging message, as the chat room is seldom used and surely, as long as the conversation stays reasonably on topic of the parent post, it is better to keep discussion concerning the topic grouped with the topic itself.  So why is there this rule?

I'm not really objecting to the idea of a chatroom, just wondering why there is so much pressure to move discussion concerning questions away from the questions themselves...
